.NET - Service bus - Moving a message to DLQ
I am using Azure Service Bus with Mass Transit library in a .NET WebApi application. I have a ServiceA where I publish my StartProccess message. This message is also used in the state machine - StartStateMachine.
This message goes to ServiceB (it is Azure Functions) where it is processed and sent on. I am forced to register the consumer for ServiceB in ServiceA using the following notation, because from what I have found and read, the subscription must pre-exist for Azure Functions. Normally, I would do this registration using MassTransit, but MassTransit cannot create a consumer without a "bind" - a consumer implementation. This is because the consumer is in a different project/service.
if (!(await adminClient.TopicExistsAsync(formatter.MessageName<StartProccess>()));
    adminClient.CreateTopicAsync(formatter.MessageName<StartProccess>());
    
if (!(await adminClient.SubscriptionExistsAsync(formatter.MessageName<StartProccess>()), formatterCheckFunc.ConsumerFromMessageName<StartProccess>()).Value)
    await adminClient.CreateSubscriptionAsync(new CreateSubscriptionOptions(formatter.MessageName<StartProccess>(), formatterCheckFunc.ConsumerFromMessageName<StartProccess>()) { MaxDeliveryCount = 1 });

The reason the max delivery count is listed here is so that when the consumer crashes on exception, it doesn't run ten times again. I want to achieve functionality like mass transit, which in case of an error immediately calls the IFault implementation and does not repeat the call.
Everything works as it should. However, once in a while and really rarely for example 1 in 100 times I get a StartProccess message that ends up in the DLQ with a message - maximum number of sends was exceeded. I don't understand why. It really sets it once in a long while. This way my state machine doesn't start and it's really clumsy.

Has anyone encountered this problem?
Thank you
Edit:
Message handling
    try
    {
        await _receiver.HandleConsumer<Consumer>(TopicName, SubscriptionName, message, cancellationToken);
        await messageActions.CompleteMessageAsync(message);
    }
    catch (SomeException ex)
    {
        await messageActions.AbandonMessageAsync(message);
        _log.LogWarning("LogIt");
    }
    catch
    {
        // This?
        await messageActions.CompleteMessageAsync(message);
        // Or this?
        await messageActions.DeadLetterMessageAsync(message);
        throw;
    }



Everything works as it should. However, once in a while and really rarely for example 1 in 100 times I get a StartProccess message that ends up in the DLQ with a message - maximum number of sends was exceeded.

Setting MaxDeliveryCount to 1 is what’s causing it.
Value of one means a single processing attempt. If that single attempt is unsuccessful for any reason, the message will be dead lettered.

I understand that, but the thing is that I send the message to the Azure function Service bus and if there is an exception, the call is repeated depending on what value is specified in MaxDeliveryCount which is awkward. So maybe it's more likely to be a problem in the Azure Function setup, because if an exception occurs in the Azure Function I don't want to repeat it.

It's not awkward—that's by design. Message processing could fail for various reasons. The function could be terminated, communication with the ASB broker could fail, etc. If you're setting MaxDeliveryCount to 1, you'll have occasional messages ending up in the DLQ. Your assumption is that an exception will only occur when there's a logical error with the message. But that's just not the case.

I understand. I understand that the max delivery count should not be one. However, I can't find a solution that if a logical error occurs in Azure Function, I don't want to repeat that call.

Usually, it's desirable to retry a message to successfully process it. In your case, there's something missing and the focus is on the how rather on why. What you're asking is exactly-once processing. Maybe elaborate on the use case and why your code should not permit message re-processing?

If there is an exception in the azure function call, I don't want to repeat it. I only want to retry it if I explicitly say (list exception) when I want to allow retrying. But I suppose I have to implement this logic myself. I've edited the question and added a sample. Throwing an exception ensures that the error queue is called and thus I know about it. Is it better to move the message to dlq or mark it as completed?

If you cannot do anything about the message, just let it be completed or complete yourself if you handle message settlement manually. Dead-lettering makes sense if you need to be able to review or later manually retry those messages. But since you're using MassTransit, it has a better mechanism - an error queue. I'd look into potentially leveraging that over DLQ.
